# Override not echoing my string or dom element

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

Hi all I'm kind of new to WordPress.  I have created an override for WooCommerce and I'm trying to echo a DOM element with an Advanced Custom Field in it.

I've used this code.

```
<?php
if (the_field('price_per_unit'))
{
    echo '<span class="unit-price">Price per unit: ' .  the_field('price_per_unit') . '</span>';
}
echo '<p>Test</p>';
?>
```

The custom field arrives, so I know I'm in the right file, but the `<p>` does not and the word "Test" does not.

Can anyone explain why this happens and how I can get my DOM elements to appear?

I thought it might be some kind of a sanitiser to I tried echoing just the word without any HTML but that also didn't work.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thats odd - it works ok here if I simulate this as a text field but other field types may cause a problem.

Try replacing 'the_field()' with 'get_field()' in your code.

If that doesn't work - how is your field setup? Text, Number, Date etc...

Comment: It's just a text field. I'm putting it into the price override in WooCommerce.

Comment: The field works fine by the way. It's the `<p>` that doesn't work

Comment: Yes appreciate that but as the <p> output wasn't governed by the IF statement I couldn't see a reason why, other than perhaps spurious output from the field above. I can't see a reason for this not working though. Not something silly like non-standard quote marks? Replace echo with esc_html or var_dump? Odd..

Comment: Good idea, I can try that.  I can also try putting the last p in front of the field.